# Can I override new Trac ticket custom fields based on other info provided on submit?

Tags: python, customization, trac

After installing TracJsGantt on our 0.12.3 Trac install, I am trying to improve the process of setting intelligent default values for the custom date fields required by TracJsGantt to track the start and finish dates of the ticket after certain actions: create or edit ticket.

I would like Trac to automatically fill or clear these custom fields when certain ticket-workflow operations are executed, such as fill in the start_date with the current date when a ticket is accepted or assigned and set the finish_date with the current date when it is closed.

Is there another plugin that will let me define custom operations after ticket changes or a way to perform operations after a ticket is created or updated and inject this data with some logic, is there a template I could manipulate or do we need to write our own plugin for this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [DynamicFieldsPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/DynamicFieldsPlugin) allows you to set defaults or modify fields during editing.

Here are some configuration examples copied from the homepage, to give you an idea of the possibilities:

```
[ticket-custom]
effort.show_when_type = enhancement|defect

[ticket-custom]
version.clear_on_change_of = milestone

[ticket-custom]
captain.copy_from = owner (overwrite)

[ticket-custom]
cc.default_value = (pref)
cc.append = true

[ticket-custom]
milestone.set_to_milestone3_when_phase = implementation|verifying|releasing
```